# Hardware assisted virtualization on centos and 32_bit system

Tags: virtualization, xen, kvm, paravirtualization

I'm preparing my-self for RHCSA. I have a 32 bit system installed centos on it. I cant use KVM on it because KVM on it because the processor architecture.
I want you to answer my problem according to following parameters.
 How can I use KVM/ if I cant what are other ways to implement hardware-assisted virtualization.
 How long I can go with OS virtualization with Centos or other Red Hat Build.
Thanks and regards,
Ammar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Xen` and RHEL/CentOS as the Dom-0 OS if you can't use KVM at all.